# Create a repeated slide show with java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an image slideshow, the current code i have moves the image to the right and then moves it back to the left, but i want the image to move from left to the right and then come out from the left then go to the right and come out from the left.....that way repeatedly.
please help

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MImage extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(10, this);
    int x = 2, y = 2, velX = 2, velY = 2;
    Image image;
    int num = 0;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("image/cartoon.jpg");
        image = i.getImage();
        g.drawImage(image, x, velY, null);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



        if (x < 0 || x >= 1500) {
            velX = -velX;
        }

        if (y < 0 || y >= 3000) {
            velY = -velY;
        }



        x += velX;
        y += velY;
        repaint(x);
    }

}
```

class SMimage

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SMImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MImage im = new MImage();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.add(im);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Moving image");
    }

}
```

it keeps moving to the right and and back to the left

Comment: You are doing a bunch of stuff in your paint component that you should not be doing. The timer should be started once, and the imageicon should only be loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to paint the image to the left, and to the right of the centered version of the image.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, x - image.getWidth(this), velY, this);
    g.drawImage(image, x, velY, this);
    g.drawImage(image, x + image.getWidth(this), velY, this);

}
```